# как сделать сортировку по цене?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, yii2

Есть интернет магазин на Yii2 и база MySql к нему.
Есть сортировка товаров, сортировка по названию и дате простые потому что эти поля есть в таблицы Item(таблица товаров) простой ORDER BY все делает ,а цена на сайте формируется з таблицы курса валют и таблицы привязки курса валют и товаров.
Вопрос: как сделать сортировку по цене?
 [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Информации как то маловато. Либо после получения моделей товаров проставьте им цены и отсортируйте средствами PHP. Или напишите большой агрегирующий SQL запрос в котором будет вычислено поле цена и по нему укажите сортировку.

Comment: дополнительная информация на фото)
спасибо)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> формируется з таблицы курса валют и таблицы привязки курса валют и товаров.

Путь это будут таблицы `Currency` и `Item_Currency` соответственно, тогда:

```
SELECT I.*
FROM Item I
  JOIN Item_Currency IC ON I.id = IC.item
  JOIN Currency C ON C.d = IC.currency
ORDER BY IC.price * C.course ASC
```

Comment: дополнительная информация на фото)
спасибо)

Comment: @Arzek, поправил запрос..